# Update multiple records using index result of sub-query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

Let's say I have a table with data...

```
| person_id  |  priority  |
|------------|------------|
|    678     |     2      |
|    413     |     4      |
|    912     |     1      |
|    111     |     5      |
```

How can I update `priority` so that the values are contiguous? *I.e.*...

```
| person_id  |  priority  |
|------------|------------|
|    678     |     2      |
|    413     |     3      |    -- updated from 4 to 3
|    912     |     1      |
|    111     |     4      |    -- updated from 5 to 4
```

I know that I can use something like...

```
select
    row_number() over (order by [priority]) as position
from
    table_name
```

...to find a person's 'position', but how can I use this to update the same row?

The `priority` values should always start at 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE or subquery:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by [priority]) as new_priority
      from table_name
     )
update toudpate
    set priority = new_priority
    where priority <> new_priority;
```